# Bind CosmosDB Local Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Bind Azure CosmosDB on Azure Functions running locally. Any configuration is required to use this feature?

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CDPCompare
{
    public static class CallWS
    {
        [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocument)
        {
            foreach(var item in inputDocument)
            {
                log.Info(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, configuration is required for your `inputDocument` argument.

You need to use this attribute to specify the Cosmos DB name and the collection.

```
[DocumentDB("%DatabaseName%", "MyCollection")] IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocuments
```

To pick up that attribute you need to reference the NuGet package for document DB `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB`. Last I checked this NuGet package is still in pre-release so make sure you include that when searching for the package.

[image]